# Issue with SQL Query Returning Doubled Total Amount

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm encountering an issue with a SQL query that's returning incorrect totals. I've set up a SQL Fiddle here to demonstrate the problem: [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe4eb1/11/0).

Here's the schema :

```
CREATE TABLE `work_type_config` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `project_files` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `identifier_code` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `funding_lines` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_file_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `estimated_amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `notified_amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`project_file_id`) REFERENCES `project_files` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `works` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_file_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `type_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`project_file_id`) REFERENCES `project_files` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `work_type_config` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And inserts :

```
INSERT INTO `work_type_config` (`name`) VALUES
('Renovation'),
('Electrical'),
('Plumbing'),
('Painting');

INSERT INTO `project_files` (`identifier_code`) VALUES
(123456789),
(987654321),
(123123123),
(321321321);

INSERT INTO `funding_lines` (`project_file_id`, `estimated_amount`, `notified_amount`) VALUES
(1, 10000.00, 9500.00),
(2, 15000.00, 14500.00),
(2, 3000.00, 500.00),
(3, 5000.00, 4800.00),
(4, 20000.00, 19000.00);

INSERT INTO `works` (`project_file_id`, `description`, `type_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Complete renovation of the kitchen', 1),
(2, 'Installation of new electrical wiring in the living room', 2),
(2, 'Another work', 1),
(3, 'Bathroom plumbing repairs', 3),
(4, 'Repainting of the exterior walls', 4);
```

And my query :

```
select pf.id, pf.identifier_code, fl.estimated_amount, fl.notified_amount, 
group_concat(distinct w.description separator ', ') as works, wtc.name, 
round(sum(fl.notified_amount),2) AS total_notified

from project_files pf join funding_lines fl on (pf.id = fl.project_file_id)
                      join works w on (pf.id = w.project_file_id)
                      join work_type_config wtc on (w.type_id = wtc.id)
where pf.id = 2
group by pf.id
```

I expect the result of round(sum(fl.notified_amount),2) AS total_notified to be 15000 (14500 + 500 for the project_files_id 2), but instead, I'm getting 30000. It seems like the total amount is doubled each time I add a row in the works table.

Could someone help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's because you have two records for "2" in WORKS.

Comment: @Error_2646 I know but I need to do group_concat(distinct w.description separator ',') as works in the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this does what you want, whenever you have cardinality issues like this it's pick your poison what information you want to either lose or have some ugly denormalization.

If you get your sum for total_amount before joining to anything project_file_id will become unique and you won't get that duplication. Of course now those max()'s are just showing the arbitrary greatest value and only the sum is meaningful.

https://dbfiddle.uk/IoNjGJrl

```
select
  pf.id,
  pf.identifier_code,
  fl.estimated_amount,
  fl.notified_amount,
  group_concat(distinct w.description separator ', ') as works,
  wtc.name,
  fl.total_notified AS total_notified
from
  project_files pf
  join (
    select
      project_file_id,
      max(estimated_amount) as estimated_amount,
      max(notified_amount) as notified_amount,
      round(sum(notified_amount), 2) as total_notified
    from
      funding_lines
    group by
      project_file_id
  ) as fl on (pf.id = fl.project_file_id)
  join works w on (pf.id = w.project_file_id)
  join work_type_config wtc on (w.type_id = wtc.id)
where
  pf.id = 2
group by
  pf.id
```

| id | identifier_code | estimated_amount | notified_amount | works | name | total_notified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 987654321 | 15000 | 14500 | Another work, Installation of new electrical wiring in the living room | Renovation | 15000.00 |

Comment: ChatGPT gives me the same answer but using sub query in JOIN is not really readable. I'd like to get another solution

Comment: @John This is one of those rare cases where ChatGPT is on the money. The only other option is changing your model so you don't have many:many on project_files.id = works.project_file_id . When you have many:many it's inevitable that you have to flatten it in some way and a subquery is about as readable as it'll get. If you wanted to avoid a subquery and are using MySQL >=8.0 you could probably finagle something with window functions, but that won't be any more concise or readable.

Comment: I'm building SQL views for my customers. Do you think it's better if I remove all many:many from this views, create another view with just works by project with columns (project_file_id, works (with comma separated) and when I build my view I'm using a join to this new table ?

Comment: @John Yes, that sounds perfectly reasonable if there is no option to change the physical model. Flattening "works" in a view would resolve the many:many. If you are absolutely positive a project_file_id will never have the same notified_amount twice you could change your sum to sum(distinct ...), but that's risky as all get out.

Comment: Okay thank you for you advise